# Reverse populate mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to figure out how to populate my business orders using the businessId property in my orders collection.

I tried this but can't get it work.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-reverse-populate

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong or other suggestions for how to accomplish what I need to do?

```
Business.findById(id).exec(function(err, business) {

        var opts = {
            modelArray: business,
            storeWhere: "orders",
            arrayPop: true,
            mongooseModel: Order,
            idField: "businessId"
        };

      reversePopulate(opts, function(err, businessAndOrders) {
        req.business = businessAndOrders;
        next();
      });
    });
```

--

```
var BusinessSchema = new Schema({
businessName:{
  type:String
}
/*.......*/

 });

var OrderSchema = new Schema({
  data: {
  type: String,

}
created: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
},
  businessId: {
  type: Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Business'
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Populate Virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) to achieve reverse populate. (Mongoose version > 4.5.0)

For case please refer official doc as link above or https://stackoverflow.com/a/51664307/3210050