# How to retrive profile and user schema with mongoose in one command?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How to have user and profile together?

This is how `User` schema defined:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String },
  picture: { type: String },
});
```

and Profile schema:

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  setting1: { type: String, enum: ['YES', 'NO', 'UNKNOWN'], default: 'UNKNOWN' },
  setting2: { type: String, enum: ['YES', 'NO', 'UNKNOWN'], default: 'UNKNOWN' },
  setting3: { type: String, enum: ['YES', 'NO', 'UNKNOWN'], default: 'UNKNOWN' },
});
```

How can I retrieve in one command/line the `profile` when I ask for user?

```
User.findOne({ email: 'blabla@gmail.com' })
```

I have try populate but it is not works:

```
User.findOne({ email: 'blabla@gmail.com' }).populate('profile')
```

- Please notice: I don't want to have profile in user in the same schema.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to link the Profile inside the UserSchema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  profile: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile' },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String },
  picture: { type: String },
});
```

Comment: There is solution which the user schema doesn't need to changed?

Comment: You are looking for a reverse populate feature which is not available yet.
Here find possible solutions: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691476/mongoose-reversed-population-i-e-populating-a-parent-object-based-on-the-ref

Comment: In general the cleanest solution is to structure you schema as suggested and directly populate the required data.